# linkify words using regex

Tags: javascript, regex, hashtag, linkify

I'm trying to linkify hashtags using regex, most of the cases work except when there is a word with dot at the end `hot.`, this should only linkify `#hot`, but at the same time `#hot.hot` is valid

Here is my regex code:

```
var text = "#hot#hot hot #hot #hot.hot #hót #hot_hot #hot, (#hot) #hot. hot";
text.replace(#([^\b#,() ]*)/g, '<a href="/$1">#$1</a>');
```

output:

```
<a href="/hot">#hot</a><a href="/hot">#hot</a> hot <a href="/hot">#hot</a> <a href="/hot.hot">#hot.hot</a> <a href="/hót">#hót</a> <a href="/hot_hot">#hot_hot</a> <a href="/hot">#hot</a>, (<a href="/hot">#hot</a>) <a href="/hot.">#hot.</a> hot
```

the only issue is `#hot.` should linkify only `#hot` at the same time `#hot.hot` is valid

Comment: I am unsure if the "\b" inside the character class actually does anything. There is no character that matches "\b", so all characters would be included in "[^\b]". At least it does not handle things like exclamation marks, if that was the intention.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your regex is fine, but you have to add a word boundary at the end:

```
#([^\b#,() ]*)\b
              ^-------- Here
```

**[Working demo](http://regex101.com/r/cM4kC1/1)**

[image]

Comment: Thanks, `\b` did the trick, if I use this I also dont need `,()`, I can just use `/#([^\b# ]*)\b/g`

Answer (score 0):

Give this regex a try instead:

```
/#([^\W]+)/g
```

`\w` matches only letters, numbers, and underscores. So its opposite, `\W`, matches everything that's *not* a letter, number, or underscore. Put that `\W` in a negated character class (`[^\W]`) and you get the desired result which can still match the accented characters.